# Automatically select previous OS when Windows dual boot system restarts?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, multi-boot

My computer is using a dual boot setup with two copies of Windows 7 installed. Currently the computer will automatically boot into the default OS whenever it restarts. Is it possible to have my computer boot to the last used OS instead? (ie, the default option would change depending on which OS was booted the previous time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible in windows 7, however in windows 8 it presents you the last user you logged in with, but for os selection it always go with default os not last logged in os